# MySql ReplicationDriver - Tomcat won't start when slave is down

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

Here is my tomcat context.xml file with my config for MySql (1 master / 1 read replica).

```
   <Resource auth="Container" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.ReplicationDriver" 
        defaultAutoCommit="false"
        initialSize="3" 
        logAbandoned="false"
        maxActive="200" 
        maxIdle="10" 
        maxWait="10000" 
        name="jdbc/powerptc" 
        removeAbandoned="true" 
        testOnBorrow="true" 
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
        username="username" 
        password="password"   
        url="jdbc:mysql:replication://localhost:3306,2.2.2.222:3306/mydb?autoReconnect=true&amp;allowSlaveDownConnections=true&amp;readFromMasterWhenNoSlaves=true&amp;connectTimeout=15000&amp;socketTimeout=15000" 
        validationQuery="/* ping */ SELECT 1"/>
```

My issue is when the slave (2.2.2.222) is down, I tomcat won't start.  I was hoping to configure it so that tomcat would still start with a slave down, and just use the master for all queries is this possible?